# Is it correct to capitalize a pronoun's first letter after a punctuation mark in a dialogue?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, dialogue

"I wonder," I said to myself, "if there's a punctuation mark at the end of a dialogue, should I capitalize a pronoun's first letter?"

"I don't know," someone in my mind said, "should we?"

"Should we?" [Another/another] one asked.

With that question, everyone in my head—even I—wondered if we should, or should not.

Comment: If the pronoun is "I", absolutely!

Comment: @PeterShor "I" is definitely capitalized be default, but what about "he", "she", and "it"? **repeats the title of this question**

Comment: The question mark used after *"Should we?"* marks the end of dialogue but is not a terminal punctuation of the sentence. It should be *another* (lowercase) in your example.

Comment: @Jason Bassford for clarification, does that also apply to the 3rd-person pronouns (or whenever I address someone in 3rd-person) as well?

Comment: @CSMAlternate  It has nothing to do with the pronoun (unless, like *I*, it's always capitalized), but the fact that some punctuation at the end of a quote does not end the sentence and, therefore, the next word is in lowercase. It depends on the context.

Comment: Confusion arises from your using the first-person singular pronoun "I", which is always capitalised, wherever it appears. So consider the position as regards capitalisation of the third person in the following sentence. *"I wonder", he said to himself...* It categorically would not be correct to capitalise the H in "he".